# jquery-file-upload POST and nested route - getting no route matches PATCH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, jquery-file-upload

In my rails4 app, I have a model **Product** which has many **ProductImages**. I am trying to get jquery file upload to create the images in the parent form by using a file_field, and i have my field set to autoupload when a file is selected. I only have create and destroy methods in my Product_images controller.

However, when it trys to post to the URL: "/products/1/product_images" I get a routing error.

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/products/1/product_images"
```

I see in the browser console that my request method is "POST", but the rails app is trying to match it as PATCH...

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://appname.dev/products/1/product_images
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

What is causing the app to use PATCH?

---

**Routes.rb**

```
resources :products do
  resources :product_images, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

**Form partial for images**

```
<fieldset id="product-images">
    <%= file_field_tag "product_images[]", type: :file, id:"file-select", multiple:true %>
    <% f.fields_for :product_images do |builder| %>
        <%= render "product_images/product_image", f:builder %>
    <% end %>
</fieldset>
```

**My Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    /* ---IMAGE AREA--- BEGIN */
    //JQ FILE UPLOAD FUNCTION
    var formURL = $(".edit_product").attr("action") + "/product_images";
    $('#file-select').fileupload({
        url:formURL,
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'script',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<div class="img uploading"/>').appendTo("#product-images");
            data.submit();
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            console.log(data.result);
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                console.log(file);
            });
            //$(".no_images").addClass("hidden");
        },
        option: {
                autoUpload: true,
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
class ProductImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product_image, only: [:show, :destroy]

  def show
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @product_image = @product.product_images.create(product_image_params)

    if @product_image.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    else 
      render :json => [{:error => "custom_failure"}], :status => 304
    end

  end

  def destroy
    @product_image.destroy
    render :json => true
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product_image
      @product_image = ProductImage.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_image_params
      params.require(:product_image).permit(:product_id, :file, :title, :caption)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to create `product_image` in product edit form, when `JqueryFileUpload` plugin sends data to server, it sends all form data.

Inspect the generated HTML by `form_for` method and search for hidden field named method. You'll find out that the value is `patch`:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch">
```

[Rails use this param to determine if POST is an PUT, PATCH or DELETE](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark)

You have two options to solve this (I would prefer the first):

1. Add `patch` route to your routes file routing to product_images#create action:
2. Edit `_method` value in [formData](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#formdata) callback function of jqueryFileUpload plugin

Comment: Am I approaching this the wrong way? With jquery-file-upload I only want to add an associated ProductImage to the Product, and do not need to update the Product record when adding a ProductImage. It looks like its sending all the Product form data which i do not need. I have done this in the past with a seperate form in the page for the association records, and a hidden product_id field inside this form to make the association, but i was hoping to keep the file_field within the parent form on this one.

Comment: No, the default of jquery-file-upload is send all form data. If you want to edit the data you send to server, use [formData](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#formdata) function.

Comment: I understand that i can overwrite using formData... but should i just post using a seperate form exclusive to product_images, rather than use the nested product form for creating new images? that is how i did it in my past projects

Comment: Yes, even better if you can use exclusive form for images.

Comment: Sometimes, due to screen layout, I couldn't use exclusive form. In these cases, I used the first solution mentioned above